# Sketching graph Exponential and logarithmic functions.

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

> Sketch the graph of each of the following (labelling asymptotes), and state the range of each: $y=3^x+1$
>   is below graph. I have no idea, how can it get $(0,2)$ i know that the $+1$ is asymptotes, Isn't it $(0,2)$ suppose to be $(0,3) $accroding to the equation.

[image]

Appreciate your explaination!
thanks

Comment: It’s right: $3^0+1=1+1=2$, so $y=2$ when $x=0$.

Comment: i understand now! thx alot, can I delete my question. it seem very easy!

Comment: You could delete it, or in a few hours $-$ I forget how long you have to wait $-$ you could answer it yourself and accept your own answer. This is perfectly acceptable; in fact, it’s encouraged.

Comment: You can delete your own question if it's got no answers yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yes, the graph plotted above is correct because 
>   $y=3^x+1$, $x=0$ 
>   $y=3^0+1$
>   $y=1+1$ 
>   $y=2$ when $x=0$ 
>   so, the graph plotted it correct!